# Soap web service is no accessible from android emulator?

Tags: android, soap, android-emulator, android-ksoap2

Hi I am consuming a soap web service from my android application, I was able to get the response from my desktop browser where as it is not working in android emulator's browser and also in my application which runs on the emulator.

Comment: put your code and logcat..

Comment: @Segi: I can't access the web service from my android emulator's browser itself then how come it will work in my app it's throwing IOException Http request failed Http status 500 internal server error

Comment: then something wrong with webserver..

Comment: Is it compulsory to use SOAP for your application? I am asking because when we used it, it takes almost 8 sec of req/res time. And we have to change that scenario to JSON HTTP req/res. And emulator have very down settings for web service call. Even though if you call any web service though it is simple HTTP, it will take twice or thrice time then device.

Comment: @Chintan Rathod: I am just consuming the soap service someone from client side is handling the soap service and yes soap is compulsory

Comment: @ArunPaarthi, If you can afford some second hand device, just purchase it and will solve your problem. 2.7" device will be fine. You just need to check one time whether service are working fine or not. And what `Bhavesh Patadiya` has given solution, will worked coz i had also done the same thing.

Comment: I have devices but even in devices also it's not working both in 3G and from my office network wifi.

Answer (score 2):

> If you are referring your localhost on your system from the Android
>   emulator then you have to use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/`. Because Android
>   emulator runs inside a Virtual Machine(QEMU) therefore here 127.0.0.1
>   or     localhost will be emulator's own loopback address.

While calling the Webservice from your Emulator Web Browser Verify that `10.0.2.2` is your machine address(run ifconfig to verify it )

let say if your webservice is

```
 http://localhost:39064/AndroidServiceImpl.svc/..
```

then while calling this from your emulator you have to use `10.0.2.2` instead `localhost`

you should call webservice like

```
 http://10.0.2.2:39064/AndroidServiceImpl.svc/..
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Actually it was hosted in amazonaws.com web service and I can access it from my desktop